# How to get my router to forward IP address to web app?

Tags: router, proxy, ip, iis

My web server is behind a Microtik router v6.1. My web app is only able to see the router's IP when referencing "REMOTE_ADDR" or "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" (asp.net app). How do I enable "IP forwarding" (or disable some kind of proxy) so that I can see the end-user's IP address?

Here is a sample IIS log:

```
2014-11-25 00:02:14 10.10.0.101 GET /email.png - 443 - 10.10.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+.NET4.0E;‌​+.NET4.0C;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+MDDCJS) https://www.example.com 304 0 0 93
```

10.10.0.101 - Server IP

10.10.0.1 - Router IP